# Questions about GAS and treeitems

Tags: checkbox, google-apps-script, treeview

Using GAS I created an UIapp containing a tree withe several (nested) treeitems.
Some of these treeitems do have checkboxes.

I would like to know:

1) if a treeitem does know about the parent widget is has been attached to

2) how to traverse a tree starting from the root

3) does a method exist to retrieve an item  (like : `item = tree.getItemById(<id>);`)

4) I noticed the onSelectionHandler of a treeItem will be called if the checkbox (of that treeitem) does NOT have an onClickHandler attached. But it will NOT be called if a checkbox has been attached to the treeitem. Can this be confirmed by somebody? If so : why dooes this happen? Do I need a callbackfunction on the checkbox in order to let the treeitem know as well?

5) As it will take long (but it works) to create a tree with a few hundred (nested) treeitems, I want to create the treeparts that are visible and after clicking on the + button to expand a level, I will just add those items I require for expanding the tree. How do I detect if the user clicks the  + button next to the treeitem in order to expand it (what eventhandler to use) ?

6) Is it possible to override class Tree and create a derived class that implements missing features discussed above?

Answer (score 0):

I started investigating GAS about 3 weeks ago and, while searching SO, I found out that a lot of things are not easy compared to other languages.

One of the things being hard is finding out what parameters are present in eventInfo in an eventhandler. I didn't find a post how to the get the names of the controls. But I know it should be possible as `JSON.stringify(e)` does write the names of the parameters.

While examining a tree I needed references to treeItems, so I figuered out how to obtain the names of controls added in an eventhandler.

I used onMouseUpHandler while performing UI-actions on the tree, but other handlers might be used as well.

Function validateParameter allows to find out if a paramater refers to a control or not.
In my application I created treeItems containing checkboxes allowing identification of the folders I want to show.
For identification of the controls I used the folderId and a prefix containing an underscore in order to discriminate between a control I added and other parameters of eventInfo.

As my goal is populating parts of tree at the time when needed (so : after the user clicks on the expand-a-branch-button next to a treeitem), I just added a 'level' indicator while creating the tree. Of course this feature can be removed.

```
var chkPrefix = "chk_"; // Prefix for names and ids of checkboxes on treeitems
var triPrefix = "tri_"; // Prefix for names and ids for treeitems  

var useCheckBox = true; // Test using checkboxes --> change accordingly
                        // false = Do not use checkboxes on treeitems
                        // true  = Use checkboxes on treeitems

  // Create various handlers
  var onSelectHandler = app.createServerHandler("onSelectHandler");
  var onMouseUpHandler = app.createServerHandler("onMouseUpHandler");
  var onCheckBoxHandler = app.createServerHandler("onCheckBoxHandler");  

// Create a tree of folders starting from 'My Drive' -->  to the folder you want
  var tree = app.createTree().setAnimationEnabled(true);
  var rootTree = DriveApp.getRootFolder();            // Root of the drive --> change to the folder you want
  var level = 3;    // Allowed maximum depth of the tree (0 = ALL) --> avoiding excessive runtime --> building treeitems when needed 
  var rootItem = populateFolderTree_(rootTree, tree, level); // 

  function populateFolderTree_(folder, parentItem, level)
  { // Internal function 
     var itemName = folder.getName();
     var itemId = folder.getId();
     if (useCheckBox === false)
     { // Just sho the name of the folder
        var treeItem = app.createTreeItem(itemName);
     }  
     else
     { // Create a checkbox on every treeitem 
        var chkBox = app.createCheckBox(itemName)
                        .setId(chkPrefix + itemId).setName(chkPrefix + itemId);
        chkBox.addClickHandler(onCheckBoxHandler);  // Add a handler
        var treeItem = app.createTreeItem(chkBox);
     }  
     treeItem.setId(triPrefix + itemId);
     parentItem.addItem(treeItem);

     if ((level === 0) || (level > 1))
     { // Maximum depth of the tree has not been reached (yet)
        var subLevel = level - 1;
        var subFolders = folder.getFolders();
        while (subFolders.hasNext())
        { // Recursively add subfolders
           var subFolder = subFolders.next();
           populateFolderTree_(subFolder, treeItem, subLevel);
        }  
     }

     return treeItem; // Will eventually return the root of the tree
  }
```

Even though this code is not complete, I believe both parts (generating the tree of folders partially, retrieving the names of parameters of evenInfo) can be useful for others as well.

```
function onMouseUpHandler(e)
{ 
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var source = e.parameter.source;               // Contains the Id of the tree
  var widget = app.getElementById(source);

  Logger.log('\nOnMouseUpHandler ' + source + '    widget=' + widget.getId() + ' = ' + widget.getType());

  var eventParameters = extractParameters(e, validateParameter);
  var numParams = eventParameters.length
  if (numParams > 0)
  {  
     var keys = eventParameters.keys();
     var values = eventParameters.values(); 

     for (var i=0; i<numParams; i++)
     {
        Logger.log('key[' + i + '] = ' + keys[i] + '   value = ' + values[i]);
     };  
  };   
  return app;
}

function validateParameter(namePar, valuePar)
{ // Skip all parameters not referring to treeitems
   var accept = false;
  var xx = namePar.substr(0, chkPrefix.length);
   if (chkPrefix === namePar.substr(0, chkPrefix.length))
   {
      accept = true;
   }
   else if (triPrefix === namePar.substr(0, triPrefix.length))
   {
      accept = true;
   };
   Logger.log('namePar=' + namePar + '   accept=' + accept + '   xx=' + xx);
   return accept;
}  

function extractParameters(e, validateFunction)
{
   var text = JSON.stringify(e);

   start = text.indexOf(':{') + 1;
   letters = text.indexOf('}') - start; 

   Logger.log('text=' + text);
   var arrParameters = text.replace('"','').substr(start, letters).split(",");

   var skipValidation = ((validateFunction === null) || (validateFunction === undefined));

  // Store parameters in a hashtable 
   var statusControls = new HashTable();   // Any hashtable will do 
   var numParameters = arrParameters.length;
   for (var i=0; i<numParameters; i++)
   {
      var parameter = arrParameters[i];
      var pos = parameter.indexOf(":");
      var nameVar = parameter.substr(1, pos - 2);
      var valueVar = parameter.substr(pos + 2, parameter.length - pos - 3);
      var accept = true;
      if (skipValidation === false) accept = validateFunction(nameVar, valueVar);
      if (accept === true) statusControls.addItem(nameVar, valueVar); // Only store acceptable parameters
   }  

   return statusControls;
}
```

As I used JSON.stringify followed by decoding its output, this method of obtaining controls can be improved for sure. But like I wrote before : I didn't find at SO how to do that, so I made it myself.

I would like to create a derived class from Tree (and maybe from TreeItem as well) doing things that are common in other languages (i.e. retrieving itemCount() at any level; walking the tree in both directions; retrieving the status of checkboxes on treeItems at any time etc.) as that is really missing at the time being (at least in my opinion), making it hard to develop.

Obviously, after just 3 weeks of GAS (and Javascript) I can't expect to know a lot. As there are plenty of people here who do have knowledge I'm missing, I hope they will help by improving code and informing me how things can be achieved.

One last remark:
I discovered that `BetterLog` indeed makes developing a lot easier compared to the standard Logger. Have a look at `https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/betterlog#TOC-Documentation-Support-Resources`